# How to skip the first element in a dictionary when using a for loop to iterate through the dictionary?

Tags: python

In a nested dictionary, something like this:

```
testDict = {
  "date1" : {
    "child1" : {
    "name" : "Emil",
    "year" : 2004
  }},
  "date2" : {
    "child2" : {
    "name" : "Tobias",
    "year" : 2007
  }},
  "date3" : {
    "child3" : {
    "name" : "Linus",
    "year" : 2011
  }}
}
```

I want to use a for loop to iterate through the dictionary, `for date in testDict:` but I want to skip the first element, depending on whether date1 matches today's date. But I couldn't even get to the logic of conditionally skipping the first element, because I don't know how to skip the first element.

Using responses to similar issues with lists, I tried:
`for date in testDict[1:]` but that gives error:
"TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'"

How can skip the first element in a dictionary when using a for loop to iterate through the dictionary?

Comment: `for key in list(testDict.keys())[1:]: frobnicate(testDict[key])`. Note that dics are orderered only in the last versions of Python, you may want to use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Got it, thanks. You grab the keys into a list, then use list slicing, where I was trying to use list slicing on the dictionary itself. Re: ordered dictionaries, the particular dictionary I'm working with is fetched via an API and comes ordered.